# Control access on the front end if the user is logged in. Should I use Redis (Backend) or Cookies?

Tags: java, angular, spring-security, redis, session-cookies

I'm using Angular and Spring Boot.

When the user logs into the website, my backend with Spring Security creates a session and stores it in the Redis database. This session is a cookie **SESSION** sent in each request from the backend to the frontend and vice versa. (For more information: https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/)

I want to know if, to control access to some frontend functionality, for example, whether the user can see a link or not depending on whether they are logged in, I should do a simple Redis query to compare the session ID or if I should create a cookie that says the user is authenticated.

Note: I can't use the **SESSION** cookie because it is HttpOnly = true.

I'm learning web development, so if you could explain it to me, I'd be very grateful.

I ask this because I believe that querying Redis every time I want to render something on the frontend can overload the system, but I don't know if this is the most used alternative.

Using Redis it would look like this:

#### Backend AuthService:

```
    public boolean isAuthenticated(HttpServletRequest request) {

        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);
        if (httpSession == null) {
            return false;
        }

        String sessionId = httpSession.getId();

        String username = getUsername();

        if (username == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return redisIndexedSessionRepository.findByPrincipalName(username).keySet().stream()
                .anyMatch(sessionId::equals);
    }
```

#### Backend AuthController:

```
    @PostMapping("/public/authentication/check-session")
    public boolean checkSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return authService.isAuthenticated(request);
    }
```

#### Frontend AuthService:

```
  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.httpClient.post<boolean>(`${this.url}/public/authentication/check-session`, null);
  }
```

Comment: you just ask the server for the user object and what roles the user has and depending on what roles the server answers with you show what should be shown in the ui

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for your answer! So I simplify the logic and avoid querying Redis by just returning a String of authorities that I get from the SecurityContextHolder? I appreciate it and found it very interesting. Am I right in my reasoning?

Comment: you login, get a session cookie, next request you ask for instance for /api/user and get the user object back that also declare what roles the user has.